# flink FileSink with bulk format to s3: rolling policy & how to specify size/time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use the FileSink to write parquet files to S3.

From the docs https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/

> For Bulk-encoded Formats we roll on every checkpoint and the user can specify additional conditions based on size or time.

It is not clear to me how to set the conditions based on size or time for bulk formats.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to know how we can set a rollover of a file based on time and size? Cause it's already mentioned in the documentation https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/#row-encoded-formats

Comment: `.withRolloverInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(10))`



etc: this is for row encoded formats.
for buk encoded formats it explicitly says one needs to use a `CheckpointRollingPolicy`, and it is not clear how to configure one with sizee/time conditions

Answer (score 3):

So there are two types of RollOverPolicy

1. `DefaultRollingPolicy`
2. `OnCheckpointRollingPolicy`

### What is Roll Over Policy?

The RollingPolicy defines when a given in-progress part file will be closed and moved to the pending and later to a finished state.

Let's try to understand both the Policies.

#### DefaultRollingPolicy:

This policy rolls a part file if:

- there is no open part file,
- the current file has reached the maximum bucket size (by default 128MB),
- the current file is older than the roll over interval (by default 60 sec),
- the current file has not been written to for more than the allowed inactivity time (by default 60 sec).

And these default values can be overriden by

```java
final FileSink<String> sink = FileSink
    .forRowFormat(new Path(outputPath), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8"))
    .withRollingPolicy(
        DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
            .withRolloverInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(10).getSeconds())
            .withInactivityInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(10).getSeconds())
            .withMaxPartSize(MemorySize.ofMebiBytes(1).getBytes())
            .build())
    .build();
```

#### OnCheckpointRollingPolicy:

A RollingPolicy which rolls (ONLY) on every checkpoint. So basically the file role over happens when Flink does its checkpointing. Here file size and time don't come into the picture.
The checkpoint interval you specify to flink via the below code also ties the interval of the roll-up of FileSink

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

// start a checkpoint every 1000 ms
env.enableCheckpointing(1000);
```

Hence for `OnCheckpointRollingPolicy` you don't have any configurations that you can set.

```java
final StreamingFileSink<String> sink = StreamingFileSink
                .forRowFormat(new Path("some"), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8"))
                .withRollingPolicy(OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.build())
                .build();
```

Comment: so that means the docs are incorrect?

as it says, see my link above

"and the user can specify additional conditions based on size or time."

Comment: Flink has an abstract class called `CheckpointRollingPolicy` which can be implemented, but as of 1.14, only two available Concrete Classes are available i.e `DefaultRollingPolicy` and `OnCheckpointRollingPolicy`. Users can always implement `CheckpointRollingPolicy` or `RollingPolicy` classes to get their desired  Rolling Policy.

Comment: this is not the behaviour I see. my own CheckpointRollingPolicy.shouldRollOnProcessingTime is not called, and on checkpoint interval it is rolled anyway. so there seems no way to configure rolling driven by size/time for the bulk format

Answer (score 1):

This can be made to work, but requires extra effort if you are using the DataStream FileSink. You can't get there with `OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.build()`; instead you will have to extend `CheckpointRollingPolicy` and override the relevant methods.

The Table API supports this out of the box with the implementation below; you could do something similar (or use a Table instead).

```java
/** Table {@link RollingPolicy}, it extends {@link CheckpointRollingPolicy} for bulk writers. */
public static class TableRollingPolicy extends CheckpointRollingPolicy<RowData, String> {

    private final boolean rollOnCheckpoint;
    private final long rollingFileSize;
    private final long rollingTimeInterval;

    public TableRollingPolicy(
            boolean rollOnCheckpoint, long rollingFileSize, long rollingTimeInterval) {
        this.rollOnCheckpoint = rollOnCheckpoint;
        Preconditions.checkArgument(rollingFileSize > 0L);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(rollingTimeInterval > 0L);
        this.rollingFileSize = rollingFileSize;
        this.rollingTimeInterval = rollingTimeInterval;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollOnCheckpoint(PartFileInfo<String> partFileState) {
        try {
            return rollOnCheckpoint || partFileState.getSize() > rollingFileSize;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollOnEvent(PartFileInfo<String> partFileState, RowData element)
            throws IOException {
        return partFileState.getSize() > rollingFileSize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollOnProcessingTime(
            PartFileInfo<String> partFileState, long currentTime) {
        return currentTime - partFileState.getCreationTime() >= rollingTimeInterval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

It seems though that  `shouldRollOnCheckpoint` for bulk formats cannot return `false`, I got essentially: 

Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointException: Could not complete snapshot 1 for operator Source: .... Failure reason: Checkpoint was declined.
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Bulk Part Writers do not support "pause and resume" operations.
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.BulkPartWriter.persist(BulkPartWriter.java:54)


can it be that it behaves differently to the Table API

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Bulk formats must roll on checkpoint. But they can, additionally, roll on event or processing time.

Comment: Has anyone been able to successfully configure roll on event or time by extending CheckpointRollingPolicy? I tried this approach but I always get the same exception pointed out by @mischa-ca ('Bulk Part Writers do not support "pause and resume" operations.').

Comment: Hello @DavidAnderson, I'm not sure If I understand what you mean by "Bulk formats must roll on checkpoint. But they can, additionally, roll on event or processing time.". Essentally it raises the same doubt I have when I read on the the Flink File Sink official docs: "Bulk formats must roll on checkpoint. But they can, additionally, roll on event or processing time."

Let's say I have a Flink app configured to enable checkpoints every 1 min. Can write parquet files to S3 every every 5 min instead?

I am using Flink 1.15.2.

Comment: With bulk formats, checkpointing isn't possible without rolling. So with checkpointing happening every 1 min, you must roll at least every minute. But if you wanted to roll even more, you could.