# How can we do minute level partition data with Flink S3 sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink S3 sink and by default Flink is partitioning data hourly. Is there any way to partition data based on every minute in S3 bucket?
Sharing of any code reference/documentation would be very helpful.

Comment: See the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70288006/2000823 for some examples and pointers.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Can you also please help me on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045352/can-we-set-bucketcheckinterval-value-with-flink-checkpointrollingpolicy