# Can we modify S3 write/commit time with Flink S3 sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using Flink bulkWriter with OnCheckpointRollingPolicy. Checkpointing interval is set at 35sec which means all s3 write/commit happens on 35th sec. I have noticed few scenario where due to intermittent backpressure(for 1-5 mins) in job, checkpointing sometimes gets delayed by few seconds. We are partitioning data at minute level in s3 bucket and there is one ETL job which process this data with one minute delay. Due to some delay checkpointing, ETL job didn't find the data for that minute but it gets added later.

To solve this issue, we want to ensure that if there is data delay, delayed data should gets added in later minute folder not the previous minute folder so that ETL job will pick the past missing data in later minuite folders.

I didnt find any way to modify this s3 write time and looks like it is coupled with checkpointing time only.

Please let me know if there is any way to fix this issue.

```
FileSink.forBulkFormat(
                s3SinkPath,
                new ParquetWriterFactory<>(builder))
                .withBucketAssigner(new CustomMinuteLevelPartitionBucketAssigner())
                .withBucketCheckInterval(35000)
                .build();
```

Comment: How about using withRollingPolicy() on FileSink and giving your own implementation on when the files should roll from .inprogress to completed state ?

Comment: @SuchethShivakumar Thanks for the help. I tried to do that but found it was just rolling over file means it was moving it from processing to pending state. Actual S3 commit was only happening on Checkpoint interval. Please let me know if you know any customized rolling policy which can change S3 commit time also.

Comment: @SuchethShivakumar I tried something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70288006/flink-filesink-with-bulk-format-to-s3-rolling-policy-how-to-specify-size-time to add custom rolling policy

Comment: It is fixed in 1.15.1 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27910